# How to insert feature that allows user to select seconds at the beginning?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm about to create a little click game. It works quite well (thanks to the help of several people). To complete it I would like to add another function.

I'd like users to choose whether they want to play 5, 10 or 15 seconds when they click Start. Other seconds should be left out, otherwise it will be too complicated with the high-score.

The high-score function should then work in such a way that the high-score of 5, 10 or 15 seconds is displayed at the end, depending on what the player selects.

Enclosed you will find the code of HTML, JavaScript and stylesheet, with a high-score function for 5 seconds.

**HTML**

```
<head>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

<div><span id="time"></span> </div>
<div id="welcome">Willkommen zu unserem Reaktionsspiel! Wenn du bereit bist, klicke auf "Start"</div>
<button id="start" type=button >Start</button>
<button id="clicker" type=button>KLICK</button>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
body
{ 
width: 100%;
height:100%; 
margin: 0 auto; 
padding: 0;
background-color:black;
display:flex;
flex-direction:column;
} 

#welcome {

    font-size:20px;
    margin:auto;
    width:400px;
    height:50px;
    color:white;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:white;
    text-align:center;
    margin-top:5%;
}

#start {
    color:white;
    background-color:black;
    margin:auto;
    margin-top:0%;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:white;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:40px;
    width:100px;
    height:80px;
    transition: transform 0.7s;



}


#start:hover {

    background-color:white;
    color:black;
    cursor:pointer;
    transform: scale(1, -1);

}

#time{
    margin-top:5%;
    margin-left:5%;
    color:white;
    font-size:50px;
    display:none;
}

#clicker{
    color:white;
    background-color:black;
    margin:auto;
    margin-top:10%;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:white;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:40px;
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:35%;

}

#clicker:hover {


    cursor:pointer;


}
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
let klick = 0;
display = document.querySelector('#time');

$("#start").click(function() { //clickfunktion beim starten.
  $("#start").fadeOut(); //Der Startbutton geht weg
  $("#welcome").fadeOut(); // Das Willkommensschild geht weg

  $("#time").fadeIn(900); //Timer kommt 
  $("#clicker").animate({
    height: 'toggle'
  }); //clicker wird gestartet 

  var dauer = 5;

  startTimer(dauer); //übergibt die variable dauer, und dass die Funktion gestartet wird.  
})

function startTimer(dauer) {
  let timer = 5;
  runTimer();
  zeit = setInterval(runTimer, 1000); //zahl gibt an, wie oft die Function pro zeit wiederholt wird. Hier eine Sekunde (1000Millisekunden)
  function runTimer(){
    display.textContent = parseInt(timer); // zeigt sekunden-variable

    --timer; //setzt den timer immer einen herab

    if (timer < 0.00) {

      timer = 5;
      console.log(timer);
      $("#start").fadeIn();
      $("#welcome").fadeIn();
      $("#time").fadeOut();
      $("#clicker").fadeOut();
      $("#clicker").css("margin-top", "10%");
      $("#clicker").css("margin-left", "50%");

      alert("Sauber du hast " + klick + " klicks in 5 Sekunden geschafft!");
      alert('High Score is ' + highScore(klick));

      klick = 0
      console.log(timer);

      clearInterval(zeit);

    } //wenn timer auf 0 ist, wird alles wieder angezeigt und die Interval-Function beendet

}


};

$("#clicker").click(function() {
  let zufall = Math.floor(Math.random() * 40) - 20 //setzt eine zufällige höhe für den clicker
  let zufal = Math.floor(Math.random() * 45) //Zufällige Variable für den Linkswert

  klick = klick + 1 //setzt den zähler beim klicken eins hoch
  if (klick % 2 == 0) {
    $("#clicker").animate({
      opacity: '0.3',
      left: zufall + "%",
      top: zufal + "%"
    }, "fast"); //bewegt den Klick-Block auf eine zufällige Stelle
  } else {
    $("#clicker").animate({
      opacity: '1.0',
      left: zufall + "%",
      top: zufal + "%"
    }, "fast")

  }


});

function highScore(score) {
  var saved = 0;
  saved = parseFloat(localStorage.getItem('highScore')) || 0;
  score = parseFloat(score) || 0;

  if (score > saved) {
    saved = score;
    localStorage.setItem('highScore', score);
  }
  return saved;
}
```

Comment: Take a Drop down list and add the options with value for 5,10 and 15. Select the option when player will be playing.in jquery get the value by using var d = $("#gt option:selected").val();
    
  var dauer = parseInt(d); again in settimer function change it let timer = parseInt(dauer);

Comment: thanks for your help, can you explain this further with the drop down list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution actualy try with my system and working well .Bellow is html and js that I changed

```html
<head>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

<div><span id="time"></span> </div>
<div id="welcome">Willkommen zu unserem Reaktionsspiel! Wenn du bereit bist, klicke auf "Start"</div>
<select id="gt" style="position:fixed;right:300px;top:65px;height:40px;width:100px;">
    <option value="5">five second</option>
    <option value="10">Ten second</option>
    <option value="15">Finteen second</option>
</select>
<button id="start" type=button >Start</button>
<button id="clicker" type=button>KLICK</button>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
</body>
```

```js
let klick = 0;
display = document.querySelector('#time');

$("#start").click(function() { //clickfunktion beim starten.
  $("#start").fadeOut(); //Der Startbutton geht weg
  $("#welcome").fadeOut(); // Das Willkommensschild geht weg

  $("#time").fadeIn(900); //Timer kommt 
  $("#clicker").animate({
    height: 'toggle'
  }); //clicker wird gestartet 
    var d = $("#gt option:selected").val();
    
  var dauer = parseInt(d);

  startTimer(dauer); //übergibt die variable dauer, und dass die Funktion gestartet wird.  
})

function startTimer(dauer) {
    let timer = parseInt(dauer);
  runTimer();
  zeit = setInterval(runTimer, 1000); //zahl gibt an, wie oft die Function pro zeit wiederholt wird. Hier eine Sekunde (1000Millisekunden)
  function runTimer(){
    display.textContent = parseInt(timer); // zeigt sekunden-variable

    --timer; //setzt den timer immer einen herab

    if (timer < 0.00) {

      timer = 5;
      console.log(timer);
      $("#start").fadeIn();
      $("#welcome").fadeIn();
      $("#time").fadeOut();
      $("#clicker").fadeOut();
      $("#clicker").css("margin-top", "10%");
      $("#clicker").css("margin-left", "50%");

      alert("Sauber du hast " + klick + " klicks in 5 Sekunden geschafft!");
      alert('High Score is ' + highScore(klick));

      klick = 0
      console.log(timer);

      clearInterval(zeit);

    } //wenn timer auf 0 ist, wird alles wieder angezeigt und die Interval-Function beendet

}


};

$("#clicker").click(function() {
  let zufall = Math.floor(Math.random() * 40) - 20 //setzt eine zufällige höhe für den clicker
  let zufal = Math.floor(Math.random() * 45) //Zufällige Variable für den Linkswert

  klick = klick + 1 //setzt den zähler beim klicken eins hoch
  if (klick % 2 == 0) {
    $("#clicker").animate({
      opacity: '0.3',
      left: zufall + "%",
      top: zufal + "%"
    }, "fast"); //bewegt den Klick-Block auf eine zufällige Stelle
  } else {
    $("#clicker").animate({
      opacity: '1.0',
      left: zufall + "%",
      top: zufal + "%"
    }, "fast")

  }


});

function highScore(score) {
  var saved = 0;
  saved = parseFloat(localStorage.getItem('highScore')) || 0;
  score = parseFloat(score) || 0;

  if (score > saved) {
    saved = score;
    localStorage.setItem('highScore', score);
  }
  return saved;
}
```

Comment: This looks good already, thanks for that! But there is the problem, what I already mentioned in the question, that he doesn't count the high score separately, only as a whole.

Comment: What you want .you mentioned that it will be too complicated with the high-score if do not left the previous.Now do you need something else ?

Comment: I meant that it gets too complicated for EVERY second (5, 10, 15, 20, 30, etc.). The high score for 5, 10, 15 seconds, however, I would like to display.

Comment: Yes just you may add the options with value for more

Comment: Thanks! This helps me alot.